# Oracle how to use a field specified into a column for a WHERE condition

Tags: sql, oracle, where-clause

I have this table into an Oracle DB

```
+----+---+---+---+---+-------------+
| ID | A | B | C | D | CheckColumn |
+----+---+---+---+---+-------------+
|  1 | X |   |   |   | A           |
|  2 |   | X |   |   | A           |
|  3 |   |   | X |   | A           |
|  4 |   |   | X |   | C           |
|  5 |   | X |   |   | B           |
|  6 |   |   |   | X | B           |
+----+---+---+---+---+-------------+
```

where the `CheckColumn` column specify the filed that I have to use to make a WHERE.
In other words I would like to make a query like this one

```
SELECT *
FROM Table
WHERE *Column of CheckColumn for that row*='X'
```

and the resul set should be the following

```
+----+---+---+---+---+-------------+
| ID | A | B | C | D | CheckColumn |
+----+---+---+---+---+-------------+
|  1 | X |   |   |   | A           |
|  4 |   |   | X |   | C           |
|  5 |   | X |   |   | B           |
+----+---+---+---+---+-------------+
```

How can I use the value of CheckColumn into the SELECT?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may use `DECODE` to map the `CheckColumn` to the *right* column

```
select * from tab
where 
decode(checkColumn,'A',A,'B',B,'C',C,'D',D) = 'X';
```

Answer (score 2):

The way I see it, it is about dynamic SQL. Read: PL/SQL.

For example:

```
SQL> select * from test;

        ID A B C D C
---------- - - - - -
         1 X       A
         2   X     A
         3     X   A
         4     X   C
         5   X     B
         6       X B

6 rows selected.
```

Function:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_test
  2    return sys_refcursor
  3  is
  4    l_str varchar2(4000);
  5    rc    sys_refcursor;
  6  begin
  7    for cur_r in (select distinct checkcolumn from test) loop
  8      l_str := l_str || 'select * from test where checkcolumn = ' || chr(39) ||
  9               cur_r.checkcolumn || chr(39) ||' and ' || cur_r.checkcolumn || ' = ''X'' union all ';
 10    end loop;
 11
 12    l_str := rtrim(l_str, ' union all ');
 13    open rc for l_str;
 14    return rc;
 15  end;
 16  /

Function created.
```

Testing:

```
SQL> select f_test from dual;

F_TEST
--------------------
CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

CURSOR STATEMENT : 1

        ID A B C D C
---------- - - - - -
         1 X       A
         4     X   C
         5   X     B


SQL>
```

Answer (score 1):

One method is a lot of boolean logic:

```
where (checkcolumn = 'A' and a = 'X') or
      (checkcolumn = 'B' and b = 'X') or
      (checkcolumn = 'C' and c = 'X') or
      (checkcolumn = 'D' and d = 'X')
```